# Add commas to a number in a popup in Leaflet JavaScript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I've created a popup that has a number in it.  The data is being imported from a geoJSON file.  Is there a way to include a comma separator? I've tried ".toLocaleString()" and ".toString()".  Assistance with my syntax would be appreciated, thank you.

```
layers.one = L.geoJson(data, {
            filter: function (feature, layer) {
                return (feature.properties.list_price <= 250000);
            },
            // Creates popup
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                // console.log(layer)  // To test for function operation
                layer.bindPopup(
                    '<h3>' +
                    feature.properties.full_address +
                    '</h3><hr><p>' +
                    '$' +
                    feature.properties.list_price.toLocaleString().replace(/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, ",")
                ) + '</p>'
            }
        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) constructor to build a formatter that has certain requirements. Like the type of currency you're trying to use. This is actually the working part of [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

This also doesn't require you to prefix your string with a `$` sign as the formatter will take care of the way the currency is represented.

```js
const value = 289900;

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency', 
  currency: 'USD',
});

const formattedValue = formatter.format(value);
console.log(formattedValue);
```